# Promises in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to do some work with Cloud Functions in TypeScript, and I'm having trouble with Promises.

```
const winnersObject = async (leagueId: string, round: string) : Promise<Object> => {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) { 
      const winners: { [key: string]: any} = {};
      return firestore
        .collection('matches')
        .where('leagueId', '==', leagueId)
        .where('round', '==', round)
        .where('status', 'in', finishedStatus)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.empty) { 
            console.log('No matches'); 
            reject(); 
          } //No hay partidos finalizados 
          else { 
            //Define winner
            snapshot.docs.forEach(async (doc) => {
              if (doc.data().awayScore === doc.data().homeScore) { console.log('Tie'); winners[doc.data().matchId] = 3; }
              else if (doc.data().homeScore > doc.data().awayScore) { console.log('Home win'); winners[doc.data().matchId] = 2; }
              else if (doc.data().awayScore > doc.data().homeScore) { console.log('Away win'); winners[doc.data().matchId] = 1; }
            });
            resolve(winners);
          }
        }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
  });
};

const getPicksDocuments = async (leagueId: string, round: string) : Promise<Array<Object>> => {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
      return firestore
        .collection('picks')
        .where('leagueId', '==', leagueId)
        .where('round', '==', round)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.empty) { 
            reject(); 
          } //No picks
          else { resolve(snapshot.docs); }
        }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
   });
};
```

When I try to call these functions like this:

```
  const winners = await winnersObject(leagueId, round);
  console.log(winners, 'Finished matches');
```

I get `{ undefined: 1 } 'Finished matches'`

And when trying

```
  const allPicksDocs = await getPicksDocuments(leagueId, round);
  console.log(allPicksDocs.length, 'Picks documents');
```

I don't even get a print at all.

Comment: not your issue, but `new Promise(async` === code smell - especially since you never use `await` in the Promise executor - remove that `async` - and the `async` in `const winnersObject = async (` since you never `await` anywhere in that function AND it returns a Promise - in fact, in your first code block remove ALL `async` as you're using it where you do not need to

Comment: as to your problem ... `doc.data().matchId` is undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX great catch! Thank you!! About your first comment, just to make sure I got this right. Does that mean that async is never needed when your return is a Promise?

Comment: Firestore is much better with RxJs than promises

Comment: an sync function returns a Promise by definition - the issue is your use of `async` without `await` ... there's never a reason to make a function `async` unless you want to use `await`